# Problemas com acentos de diretórios

Tags: java

Preciso pegar o diretório de um arquivo que está dentro do projeto, mas o retorno não está respeitando os acentos das pastas.

Classe que busca o diretório:

```
package NewClass;

import java.io.File;

public class NewMain1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File root = (new File(NewMain1.class.getResource("teste.txt").getFile())).getParentFile().getParentFile();
    System.out.println(root);
    File file1 = new File(root + "\\teste.txt");
    System.out.println(file1);
}    
}
```

O caminho é: "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pedro\Aplicações\JavaApplication1\build\classes".

Mas a saída vem: "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pedro\Aplica%c3%a7%c3%b5es\JavaApplication1\build\classes".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649879/how-to-get-absolute-path-with-proper-character-encoding-in-java

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo, obrigado